# Loop within loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, python-2.4, logfile-analysis

I have a log file with several hundred thousand lines.

I am looping through these lines to find any line with some specific text, for example: `!!event!!`.
Then, once an `!!event!!` line is found, I need to continue looping after this `!!event!!` line until I find the next 3 lines which contain their own specific text `('flag1', 'flag2', and 'flag3')`.
Once I find the third line `('flag3')`, I then want to continue looping for the next `!!event!!` line and repeat the former process until there are no more events.

Does anyone have suggestions on ways I structure my code to accomplish this?

For example:

```
f = open('samplefile.log','r')
for line in f:
    if '!!event!!' in line:
            L0 = line
        #then get the lines after L0 containing: 'flag1', 'flag2', and 'flag3'
        # below is a sample log file  
        #I am not sure how to accomplish this 
        #(I am thinking a loop within the current loop) 
        #I know the following is incorrect, but the 
         intended result would be able to yield something like this:
            if "flag1" in line:
                L1 = line.split()
            if "flag2" in line:
                L2 = line.split()
            if "flag3" in line:
                L3 = line.split()
print 'Event and flag times: ', L0[0], L1[0], L2[0], L3[0]
```

samplefile.log

```
8:41:05 asdfa   32423
8:41:06 dasd    23423
8:41:07 dfsd    342342
8:41:08 !!event!!   23423
8:41:09 asdfs   2342
8:41:10 asdfas  flag1
8:41:11 asda    42342
8:41:12 sdfs    flag2
8:41:13 sdafsd  2342
8:41:14 asda    3443
8:41:15 sdfs    2323
8:41:16 sdafsd  flag3
8:41:17 asda    2342
8:41:18 sdfs    3443
8:41:19 sdafsd  2342
8:41:20 asda    3443
8:41:21 sdfs    4544
8:41:22 !!event!!   5645
8:41:23 sdfs    flag1
8:41:24 sadfs   flag2
8:41:25 dsadf   32423
8:41:26 sdfa    23423
8:41:27 sdfsa   flag3
8:41:28 sadfa   23423
8:41:29 sdfas   2342
8:41:30 dfsdf   2342
```

the code from this sample should print:

```
Event and flag times: 8:41:08 8:41:10 8:41:12 8:41:16
Event and flag times: 8:41:22 8:41:23 8:41:24 8:41:27
```

Comment: Suggestion: feed the lines to a FSM (finite state machine) that has states like find_event, find_flag1, etc.

Comment: You should use regular expressions to do this. If you show me some sample input and what you want to do with it I can teach you how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can continue to consume the file in an inner loop, then break out of it when you encounter flag3, and the outer loop will resume:

```
for line in f:
    if '!!event!!' in line:
        L0 = line.split()
        for line in f:
            if "flag1" in line:
                L1 = line.split()
            elif "flag2" in line:
                L2 = line.split()
            elif "flag3" in line:
                L3 = line.split()
                break             # continue outer loop
        print 'Event and flag times: ', L0[0], L1[0], L2[0], L3[0]

# Event and flag times:  8:41:08 8:41:10 8:41:12 8:41:16
# Event and flag times:  8:41:22 8:41:23 8:41:24 8:41:27
```

Comment: thank you and to all that have replied so far!  this is the first reply I looked at and it's very simple and works.  I'm still going to look at the other replies to see if there is more I can learn regarding this topic

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
with open("in6.txt") as f:
    flag = False
    c = 0
    d = []
    data = []
    for line in f:
        if flag:
            if "flag1" in line or "flag2" in line:
                data.append(line.split()[0])
            elif "flag3" in line:
                data.append(line.split()[0])
                flag = False
                d.append(data)

            continue
        if "!!event!!" in line:
            flag = True
            data = []
            c = 0
            data.append(line.split()[0])

for l in d:
    print "Event and flag times: ", l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3]
```

**Output**

```
>>> 
Event and flag times:  8:41:08 8:41:10 8:41:12 8:41:16
Event and flag times:  8:41:22 8:41:23 8:41:24 8:41:27
```

Comment: You never test for the proper `flag` text in the line. The assumption it is the next 3 lines is not correct here.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a flag to track what you are looking for:

```
with open('samplefile.log') as f:
    events = []
    current_event = []
    for line in f:
        if not current_event and '!!event!!' in line:
            current_event.append(line.split()[0])
        else:
            if 'flag1' in line or 'flag2' in line or 'flag3' in line:
                current_event.append(line.split()[0])
                if 'flag3' in line:  # could also be `if len(current_event) == 4:`
                    events.append(current_event)
                    current_event = []

for event in events:
    print 'Event and flag times:', ' '.join(event)
```

Here I used `current_event` as the flag; by adding the `!!event!!` line time to it it becomes non-empty and we start looking for the flags.

I collected the individual event times into a `events` list, but you could also just print the event data whenever you have found the `flag3` line.

Output:

```
Event and flag times: 8:41:08 8:41:10 8:41:12 8:41:16
Event and flag times: 8:41:22 8:41:23 8:41:24 8:41:27
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over each line, then when you find `!!event!!`, start looking for the flags, and once all flags are found, continue...

Something like:

```
def get_time(line):
    return [ i for i in line.split() if i != ''][0]

data = []
index = -1
look_for_flags = False
for line in lines:
    if '!!event!!' in line:
        look_for_flags = True
        data.append([get_time(line)])
        index += 1
    elif look_for_flags:
        if 'flag1' in line or 'flag2' in line or 'flag3' in line:
            data[index].append(get_time(line))
print data
```

Answer (score 0):

The clearest way to do this is using a `generator function`, which obviates the need to keep any state. **Whenever you need to build a state machine (like you're doing here), think `generator`.**

```
import sys

def find_target_lines(file_handle):
    target = yield
    for line in file_handle:
        if target in line:
            target = yield line

f = open('samplefile.log','r')
targets = ['!!event!!', 'flag1', 'flag2', 'flag3']

while True:
    found = list()
    finder = find_target_lines(f)
    next(finder)
    try:
        for target in targets:
            line = finder.send(target)
            if line:
                found.append(line)
        print(found)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```